# R sf "Group by Proximity"

Tags: r

Is there a way to Group by Proximity a layer using SF library?

Similar to this tool from Arcgis: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/geoanalytics-desktop/group-by-proximity.htm

[image: Example from ArcGIS]

Comment: Hello! You should provide a [minimal reproducible example of your code and data along with relevant errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also apply a kmeans clustering on the spatial coordinates of each circle, to group them in the desired number of clusters.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# Reusing the data posted by Allan Cameron
points <- st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 2)), st_point(c(0, 3)), st_point(c(1, 0)),
                 st_point(c(1, 2.5)), st_point(c(2, 0.5)), st_point(c(2.5, 1)),
                 st_point(c(3, 1)), st_point(c(3, 3.5)), crs = 32617) |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  st_buffer(dist = 0.5)

# Get centroids and coordinates
centers <- points |>
  st_centroid() |>
  mutate(as_tibble(st_coordinates(x)))

# Do kmeans over the centers, set groups to 3
km <- kmeans(centers |>
               st_drop_geometry() |>
               select(X, Y), 
             centers = 3)

points |>
  # Add cluster value from kmeans as group
  mutate(group = km$cluster) |>
  # Plot
  ggplot(aes(fill = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_sf() + 
  labs(fill = "Group")
```

[image: grouped circles]

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing, the issue is that I need to replicate this on Polylines not points. My mistake I should clarify this before.

Comment: You can use a similar approach with Polylines, you just need to use `st_point_on_surface` instead of `st_centroid` to find mid points along your lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of points, you can use `st_buffer` to create circular polygons around them at a fixed radius. The following roughly imitates the given image:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

points <- st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 2)), st_point(c(0, 3)), st_point(c(1, 0)),
                 st_point(c(1, 2.5)), st_point(c(2, 0.5)), st_point(c(2.5, 1)),
                 st_point(c(3, 1)), st_point(c(3, 3.5)), crs = 32617) |>
          st_as_sf()

radii <- st_buffer(points, dist = 0.7) |> st_as_sf()

ggplot(radii) + 
  geom_sf(fill = 'lightblue', alpha = 0.5) + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

If we want to arrange these into groups, we need to figure out which polygons intersect with each other using `st_intersects`. This will produce an adjacency matrix from which we can create a graph using `igraph`. The connected components of this graph are the groups that we want:

```r
library(igraph)

radii$group <- st_intersects(radii, sparse = FALSE) |>
  graph.adjacency() |>
  components() |>
  getElement('membership') |>
  as.character()
```

Now `radii` looks like this:

```r
radii
#> radii
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -0.7 ymin: -0.7 xmax: 3.7 ymax: 4.2
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N
#>                                x group
#> 1 POLYGON ((0.7 2, 0.6990407 ...     1
#> 2 POLYGON ((0.7 3, 0.6990407 ...     1
#> 3 POLYGON ((1.7 0, 1.699041 -...     2
#> 4 POLYGON ((1.7 2.5, 1.699041...     1
#> 5 POLYGON ((2.7 0.5, 2.699041...     2
#> 6 POLYGON ((3.2 1, 3.199041 0...     2
#> 7 POLYGON ((3.7 1, 3.699041 0...     2
#> 8 POLYGON ((3.7 3.5, 3.699041...     3
```

And plotting we see these groups are correct:

```r
ggplot(radii) + 
  geom_sf(data = radii, aes(fill = group), alpha = 0.6) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('green3', 'blue3', 'red3')) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite on package `sf` since it only does basic geographic operations. But what you are looking for is spatial clustering, and R does have (multiple) algorithms for that.

The closest to your input, in my opinion, is DBSCAN. It is available in the package `dbscan`. However, your problem can also be solved using k-means, or hierarchical clustering.